# VB.NET Fill a Large File with bytes

Tags: vb.net, file-io

I'm creating a temp file to store a huge matrix that can't fit in memory. I'd like to write the temp file to disk first so I can seek to a position in the file with a stream object. I already know the exact size I need.

What's the easiest way to write, say, 2 gigabytes of zeros?

I tried writing it one byte at a time and that's really slow. I also tried writing byte array chuncks and that's a lot faster but I must suck at the math cause I can't get the final size to be what I expect.

Comment: Note also you may get O/S support to initially create a large file. See `fsutil file createnew`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ft83zssf.aspx) has a method [Seek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.seek.aspx) that allows you to set an arbitrary position on a file also if this position is outside the end of the file.
If you write a simple byte at this position, the OS will resize the file to allow the write at the requested position.

```
    Dim testfile as String = "d:\temp\testfile.bin"
    Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(testfile)
    Dim utf8 As UTF8Encoding = new UTF8Encoding()
    Dim bw As BinaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(fs, utf8)
    bw.Seek(1500, SeekOrigin.Begin) 'only 1500 bytes just for test
    bw.Write(255)
    fs.Close()
```

Comment: Nice! However 2GB is exactly one byte too large for the Int32 offset parameter in BinaryWriter.Seek. Edit, nevermind I guess since it's the offset, Int32.MaxValue would be exactly 2GB.

Comment: The parameter [SeekOrigin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/883dhyx0.aspx) could also be set to _Current_. So, write a first byte with Begin (from zero), then write another one with Current (last write pos).

Comment: Wow! This is perfect. I was afraid it would take too long to write the file in one line (bw.write(255)) but somehow, like you said, the OS optimizes it so it completes in a split second. This is perfect. It has an overload for writing filling the file with integers (zero, in my case). I was able to get the exact size I need.

Answer (score 0):

This is not terribly efficient but I wrote a 2gig file in 38 seconds, first compile in debug mode...

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i <= 4000; i++) s.Append("0");

System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch t = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"c:\temp\temp.text"))
{
      for (long i = 0; i < 2147483648; i+= 4000)
         file.Write(s.ToString());
}
this.label1.Text = t.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString();
```

2 gigs is [this much](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=stopwatch&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#hl=nl&client=opera&rls=en&channel=suggest&sclient=psy-ab&q=2gigs+to+bytes&oq=2gigs+to+bytes&gs_l=serp.3..0i13i30.238284.242074.2.242159.16.15.1.0.0.0.160.1186.9j5.14.0...0.0...1c.1.mInZNkQUzI0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=50337f75cb9611b7&biw=1887&bih=1077) according to google.

So, I don't know, how fast do you want this?